# Start placing figures on right-hand side column of first page

Tags: floats, two-column, ieeetran

I am trying to use IEEETrans to write a scientific paper in two column format. The issue is that one is not allowed to place figures in the left-hand side column of the first page. Figures should start on the top of the right-hand side column of the first page or alternatively, on the second page (any column).
Is there any way to restrict the placement of floats to avoid using the left-hand side column of the first page?

Comment: You could use \usepackage{float} and then use \begin{figure}[H] or look into the placeins package, which allows you to specify where figures can float. I am not posting this as an answer, since this is a sub-optimal solution.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[image]

You can specify no top or bottom floats in the column. (The class ought to do this in its maketitle definition)

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\title{My IEEE article}
\author{Author}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\global\csname @topnum\endcsname 0
\global\csname @botnum\endcsname 0
\begin{abstract} \lipsum[1]\end{abstract}

\section{First Section}

As you can see in Fig~\ref{fig}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\fbox{A nice figure}
\caption{A nice figure}\label{fig}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[1-5]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! It works perfectly! Also allows figures in the left column for the following pages.

Comment: This trick only seems to work for the first column or when you put in an explicit pagebreak. How would you handle not to have any floats on the entire first page, i.e. both columns?

Answer (score 2):

This is the easiest way I know: Declare your figure far from first column.

Figures are floating objects and you make reference to them with labels, so it's not necessary to be placed where you are declaring the reference but where you think (more or less) they should be placed.

Next code with figure declared near its reference, places the figure on top of left column:

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\title{My IEEE article}
\author{Author}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\begin{abstract} \lipsum[1]\end{abstract}

\section{First Section}

As you can see in Fig~\ref{fig}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\fbox{A nice figure}
\caption{A nice figure}\label{fig}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[1-5]

\end{document}
```

[image]

while, next one declares the figure a little bit later although its reference remains at the first line. This way the figure is placed on right column.

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\title{My IEEE article}
\author{Author}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\begin{abstract} \lipsum[1]\end{abstract}

\section{First Section}

As you can see in Fig~\ref{fig}

\lipsum[1-5]

\begin{figure}
\centering
\fbox{A nice figure}
\caption{A nice figure}\label{fig}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. This solution works well if you are writing continuously. Nonetheless, I would like to be able to go back and edit the initial parts of the text without having to worry about the placement of the figures.